# Paging in x86-64 architecture

Tags: kernel, x86-64, paging, mmu, page-tables

In 32 bit implementation of operating systems, page tables have a fixed structure (two levels - page directory & page table). But in x86_64 systems, there are generally multiple levels of page tables implemented (4 in Linux). How does the system know how many levels are being used? What is the command required for this? How do we let the CPU know the global page directory and other structures?

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer**:

- At the time of writing, x86-64 page tables are always 4 levels. In the future, 5 and 6 levels may be implemented to cover the full 64-bit address space.
- The OS queries the hardware capabilities by executing the CPUID instruction with various arguments.
- The OS sets the global page directory pointer by writing to the control register CR3.

**Authoritative text**: See *[Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer Manuals](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html)*, volume 3A "System Programming Guide, Part 1", section 4.5 "IA-32e Paging".

**[Wikipedia text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#Page_table_structure)** (slightly edited):

> The 64-bit addressing mode ("long mode") is a superset of Physical Address Extensions (PAE). Rather than the three-level page table system used by systems in PAE mode, systems running in long mode use four levels of page table: PAE's Page-Directory Pointer Table is extended from 4 entries to 512, and an additional Page-Map Level 4 (PML4) Table is added, containing 512 entries in 48-bit implementations. In implementations providing larger virtual addresses, this latter table would either grow to accommodate sufficient entries to describe the entire address range, up to a theoretical maximum of 33,554,432 entries for a 64-bit implementation, or be over ranked by a new mapping level, such as a PML5.